# about DbSet and Discriminator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to filter the lines of a DbSet using the Discriminator attribute. to explain more, i have a table called Employee and it contains the Discriminator attribute to specify if the Employee is a simple Employee or an Administrator. I want to change the Index view in the Employee-controller to show only the Employees and not the Administrators.
Here is the current code :

```
    //
    // GET: /Employes/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Employees.ToList());
    }
```

i want to make it like this :

```
//
    // GET: /Employee/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Employees.Where<Employee>(emp => emp.Discriminator.Equals("Employee")));
    }
```

but it doesn't work because the class Employee does not contain the attribute Discriminator. Is there any other alternative without using SqlConnection and SqlCommand ?

Here are my model classes :

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false), Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int idAdmin { set; get; }

    [Required, StringLength(16), Display(Name = "Login")]
    public string loginAdmin { set; get; }

    [Required, StringLength(16), Display(Name = "Password"), DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string passwordAdmin { set; get; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "CIN")]
    public int cinAdmin { set; get; }
}

public class Administrateur : Employee
{
}
```

Comment: the attribute Discriminator is only in the database because i have 2 classes  Employee and Administrator in my Models. the Administrator class inherits the class Employee that's why the attribute Discriminator has automatically generated in the database.

Comment: See update for better way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Employees.Where(emp => !db.Administrators.Any(a => a.Id == emp.Id));
```

this creates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeRole] AS [EmployeeRole], 
    [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    [Extent1].[AdminName] AS [AdminName]
    FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Administrator',N'Employee')) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent2].[Discriminator] = N'Administrator') AND ([Extent2].[Id] = [Extent1].[Id])
    ))
```

**EDIT** you are better of using `!(e is Administrator)`

```
ctx.Employees.Where(e => !(e is Administrator)).ToList();
```

Which creates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeRole] AS [EmployeeRole], 
    [Extent1].[IsAdmin] AS [IsAdmin], 
    [Extent1].[Age] AS [Age], 
    [Extent1].[AdminName] AS [AdminName]
    FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Administrator',N'Employee')) 
    AND ([Extent1].[Discriminator] <> N'Administrator')
```